# Git commit is staging all additional files in my repo

Tags: git, version-control

I am having an issue with git where every commit, regardless of what files are staged, is adding and committing all changed files in the repo.

I am using VS Code and Git Bash. The same issue presents itself in both of these environments. This is regardless of  what files I have specifically staged.

OS: windows
vsCode: 1.20.0
Shell 1.7.9
git: 2.16.1.4-64x

I have:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled git bash.
- Manually added files and committed via Git Bash.
  `git add ./filename.example
  git commit -m "commit message"`
- Tried using the commit staged options of VSCode.
- Looked at my .gitconfig. Only standard settings involving http: sslVerify, user settings, difftool and mergetool being set to sourcetree.
- VScode settings (checked that "git.enableSmartCommit": false).

Example of staging and committing in Git Bash  with VS Code not running:

```
Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ✓|
→ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-
forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
 (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   frontend/src/app/app.component.ts
    modified:   frontend/src/app/globals.service.ts

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ↓1 U:2 ✗|
→ git add ./frontend/src/app/app.component.ts
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/app/app.component.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ↓1 S:1 U:1 ✗|
→ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
 (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   frontend/src/app/app.component.ts

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   frontend/src/app/globals.service.ts

Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ↓1 S:1 U:1 ✗|
→ git commit -m "test commit"
backend\src\app.controller.ts 176ms
backend\src\app.module.ts 6ms
backend\src\database\database.module.ts 7ms
backend\src\database\database.tokens.ts 1ms
backend\src\database\models\index.ts 0ms
backend\src\main.ts 10ms
frontend\e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts 5ms
frontend\e2e\app.po.ts 3ms
frontend\src\app\app.component.ts 11ms
frontend\src\app\app.module.ts 8ms
frontend\src\app\app.routing.module.ts 8ms
frontend\src\app\approval\approval.component.spec.ts 6ms
frontend\src\app\approval\approval.component.ts 4ms
frontend\src\app\auth.config.ts 3ms
frontend\src\app\core\core.module.ts 2ms
frontend\src\app\globals.service.spec.ts 4ms
frontend\src\app\globals.service.ts 2ms
frontend\src\app\globals.ts 0ms
frontend\src\app\home\app.component.spec.ts 6ms
frontend\src\app\home\home.component.ts 2ms
frontend\src\app\login\login.component.spec.ts 6ms
frontend\src\app\login\login.component.ts 5ms
frontend\src\app\mission-overview\mission-overview.component.spec.ts 6ms
frontend\src\app\mission-overview\mission-overview.component.ts 11ms
frontend\src\app\missions\missions.component.spec.ts 5ms
frontend\src\app\missions\missions.component.ts 2ms
frontend\src\app\request-channels\request-channels.component.spec.ts 9ms
frontend\src\app\request-channels\request-channels.component.ts 4ms
frontend\src\app\shared\app-material.module.ts 3ms
frontend\src\app\shared\mission-status\mission-status.component.spec.ts 4ms
frontend\src\app\shared\mission-status\mission-status.component.ts 4ms
frontend\src\app\shared\shared.module.ts 2ms
frontend\src\app\validation\validate.component.spec.ts 5ms
frontend\src\app\validation\validate.component.ts 2ms
frontend\src\main.ts 2ms
frontend\src\polyfills.ts 5ms
frontend\src\test.ts 3ms
frontend\src\typings.d.ts 2ms

warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in frontend/src/app/globals.service.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master d19bf0c] test commit
 2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ↑1 ↓1 ✓|
→ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comp-NZ:  ~/Workspace/Project  |master ↑1 ↓1 ✓|
```

Comment: Have you added the offending files to .gitignore?

Comment: are you really sure the other files are not staged (maybe by a program which uses git). could you try `git status` before commiting?

Comment: Do you have VS Code running when you run `git commit` on the command-line?  What's the output of `git status` before you run `git commit` - are these files identified as "unstaged" changes or "staged" changes?  What's the output of `git status` _after_ committing?

Comment: Correct I had tried git status previously. And it showed the same as VS Code's source control interface.

Comment: Is there an alias of some sort adding `-a` (`--all`) to the `git commit`?

Comment: I've had a look through vscode's terminal and git bash's alias lists by typing alias into the terminals but neither have a ```-a``` or ```git``` alias's registered.

Comment: @JoshFogg Can you provide the remote repo which you are working with? And are there other contributors also works for the remote repo with different OS?

Comment: Sorry I the Repo is private. Although I tried in another Repo and have found that I cannot reproduce the problem which is very interesting... Must have been affected after a company internal boilerplate pull conflict..
I'll have a dig and let you know what I find.
Thanks Team

Comment: Ye it seems a precommit husky hook was added directly into the .git setup that was misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file ".gitignore" and add all files or directorys which should be ignored by GIT.

[.gitignore in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s74t.png)

Example:

```
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.prefs.xml
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xm
**/pom.properties
/target/
```

For more details see the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: This question is not about git ignoring but rather git commit causing ALL files that have changes, to be staged and committed without my input or even overriding the files I have specifically staged.

Answer (score 0):

`git commit` should not commit unstaged files. You can commit specific files using:

```
git add ./frontend/src/app/app.component.ts
git commit -m "test commit" ./frontend/src/app/app.component.ts
```

Comment: Sorry but this is irrelevant as it has already been covered in the initial question posting as a method tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: I have found the problem... Git hooks. Git Hooks are scripts that Git executes before or after events. They are located in your repo's project/.git/hooks folder. The 'pre-commit' hook seems to be meddling with my git save.
The hook is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
./node_modules/pre-commit/hook
RESULT=$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

which then redirects to this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit

The issue comes from ./node_modules/pre-commit/hook ln:49

```
"$BINARY" "$("$BINARY" -e "console.log(require.resolve('pre-commit'))")"
```